# Object moves on own with rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object in unity with a rigidbody attached to it. For some reason, the object moves forward on the Z axis, even though no script is telling it to.

Does anyone know why this is happened?

(some notes, isKinematic is turned off, freeze x, y position are on, free x, y, z position are on)

Comment: Is the rigidbody affected by gravity?

Comment: The default gravity would pull it down(-y) not forward(+z).

Answer (score 1):

An Object does not need to have a script directly attached to it for it to move. A script that is attached to another GameObject can also find this GameObject and be able to move it.

You should disable all other GameObjects with scripts. If they contain any script that is moving this GameObject, you will find out.

---

Another big possibly I've seen several times is the `Animation` or `Animator` component. These two components can move a GameObject and I suggest you remove any of them that is attached to your GameObject. It is very likely this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- An impulse could have affected it, and the velocity is still up.
- Do you have windzones in your scene?
- Try to disable the ridgidbody during play, if any script is acting on your Ridgidbody, you will get an error pointing to the class trying to use it.
- Disable the collider, see if it still moves.
- If colliders are too small, ridgidbodies tend to "dance"

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: In inspector freeze rotation X and Z in the Сonstraint of Rigidbody.
Perhaps this is a bug of the physical system. In my case, the capsule began to spontaneously go up the slope, even without any scripts and animation. Unity version 2021